# hbase-0.94.0 start up errors

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Today,I encountered a problem when starting the hbase,
 **Errors are as follows:**

**1.in hbase-localhost-zookeeper-chaobin.log**

```
2013-01-02 16:05:26,406 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:3170
2013-01-02 16:05:26,406 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:3170 as it has seen zxid 0xc our last zxid is 0x0 client must try another server
2013-01-02 16:05:26,406 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:3170 (no session established for client)
2013-01-02 16:05:27,984 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:3171
2013-01-02 16:05:27,984 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:3171 as it has seen zxid 0xc our last zxid is 0x0 client must try another server
2013-01-02 16:05:27,984 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:3171 (no session established for client)
2013-01-02 16:05:29,796 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:3172
2013-01-02 16:05:29,796 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:3172 as it has seen zxid 0xc our last zxid is 0x0 client must try another server
2013-01-02 16:05:29,796 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:3172 (no session established for client)
2013-01-02 16:05:31,750 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:3173
2013-01-02 16:05:31,750 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:3173 as it has seen zxid 0xc our last zxid is 0x0 client must try another server
2013-01-02 16:05:31,750 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:3173 (no session established for client)
```

**2.in hbase-localhost-master-chaobin.out**

```
java.io.IOException: Waiting for shutdown of standalone server
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MiniZooKeeperCluster.shutdown(MiniZooKeeperCluster.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:223)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**3.in hbase-localhost-regionserver-chaobin.log**

```
2013-01-02 16:02:10,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.VersionInfo: Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hbase/branches/0.94 -r 1332822
2013-01-02 16:02:10,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.VersionInfo: Compiled by jenkins on Tue May  1 21:43:54 UTC 2012
2013-01-02 16:02:10,531 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine: Not starting a distinct region server because hbase.cluster.distributed is false
```

Comment: can you please share some more info like your config params, kind of setup(pseudo, distributed) etc?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see form the source, the `waitForServerDown` method in the `MiniZooKeeperCluster` throws such and exception. this is because the port assigned for zookeeper server on the prescribed machine is used by some other application, or it simply is not available to carry a stream. Try changing the port to some other, or check the application running on that port.

If you are using linux, type `netstat -tulp|grep port-no` in a terminal replacing the zookeeper port, to find whether its being used by some other program or not.